# using pybind11 on MacBook Pro

Tags: python, c++, pybind11

I am trying to use pybind11 on Macbook and I am trying to do as was written in https://pybind11.readthedocs.io/en/stable/basics.html I installed cmake from there website
I created

```
mkdir build
cd build
```

but when I tried

```
cmake ..
```

I got an error

```
CMake Error: The source directory "/Users/fai" does not appear to contain CMakeLists.txt.
Specify --help for usage, or press the help button on the CMake GUI.
```

how can I fix this? I want to use pybind11 on my Mac and it seems I need to fix this issue

also I had a problem with pybind11 when using it in Xcode I wrote

```
#include <pybind11/embed.h>
```

but I got an error

```
'pybind11/embed.h' file not found
```

I installed pybind11 correctly according to there website

Comment: Can you give more information about the file structure? What is your CMakeLists.txt, it seems like you don't have any? Have you cloned or gotten any source files of pybind11?

Comment: I installed Cmake as was told by pybind11 first step and after that I did as described above. If I understand correctly the CMakeLists.txt file should be there after installing the Cmake program. Am I wrong ? The point of all of this is to embed python in C++ that is why I am following the pybind11 website to try and do the test

Comment: No the CMakeLists.txt is a file which is used by CMake to know all the settings of a project (in this case pybind11). So what you will have to do is to get the pybind11 from source and then run the specific commands you mentioned in the directory where you've put the source. It might be useful in your case to do some research on Make and CMake and know the difference and what it does.

Answer (score 0):

You can add following lines to CMakeLists.txt

```
# set pybind11 dir
set(pybind11_DIR /Users/Caleb/Softwares/pybind11)
find_package(pybind11 REQUIRED)
```